# Assasins ou NFS map GUI alike in Unity

Tags: user-interface, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game in Unity and I would like to have a map that goes along with the player and it shows his current position in the over all map. Something like this:

[image]

I am thinking in placing a plan with a culling mask and right underneath it other layer with the map that moves according to the characters position. Nevertheless I wanted to share this problem and my approach duo the fact of having more sugestions to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance, Dessain Saraiva.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back for a small architecture project, so users could see where were in the floor plan while walking around the building. My solution was to place a quad at ground level, and put the map texture I wanted on it. Then I attached a marker to my character controller, and set both of them to a new layer, and removed that layer from the character's culling map.

Next I attached a downwards facing camera onto the character controller, and set it to only view the map's layer. I was using Unity Pro, so I used a RenderTexture as the target of that camera, and then placed on a GUIbox in the top right corner.

Overall, it worked out pretty well.

Comment: Yup, your idea made the job. Thannk you!

Answer (score 0):

One approach I like to use is a copy of the terrain in a separate layer, and is only visible by the map camera floating above you.

When you copy the terrain, turn the resolution and most other settings way down, as due to you being far above the small details are not noticeable.

Now just attach the map camera above your player and it will move and rotate right along with them.